# Python Nested Loop Enter Value and Confirm Answer

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a simple block of code that has a user enter an interest rate. The number must be 0 or greater, any other value will be rejected, the user must be polled until a valid number is input. If the number is greater than 10%, the user must be asked if he/she really expects an interest rate that high, if the user replies in the affirmative, the number is to be used, otherwise the user will be asked to input the value again and the above checks will be made. I'm having trouble understanding the nested loop aspect of this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def main():

    while True:
        try:
            interest_rate = int(input("Please enter an interest rate: "))
        except ValueErrror:
            print("Entered value is not a number! ")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Command Error!")
        else:
            if 0 <= interest_rate < 10:
                break
            elif interest_rate > 10:
                print("Entered interest rate is greater than 10%. Are you sure? (y/n): ")

main()
```

Comment: What if the interest rate entered is 10?

Comment: 10 is fine. Anything above that should ask for confirmation.

Comment: and are interest rates really integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it all in the try, `if inp > 10`, ask if the user is happy and break if they are, elif user input is within threshold just break the loop:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            interest_rate = int(input("Please enter an interest rate: "))
            if interest_rate > 10:
                confirm = input("Entered interest rate is greater than 10%. Are you sure? (y/n): ")
                if confirm =="y":
                    break
            elif 0 <= interest_rate < 10:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Entered value is not a number! ") 
    return interest_rate

main()
```

Comment: In hindsight, doing everything in one go makes a lot more sense. I'm fairly new to programming so I tend to try to do things block after block after block. This looks much more efficient though. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, no prob,you're welcome,  it should be  a little easier to read and do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Three things jump out:

1) `ValueErrror` should be `ValueError`

2) You don't handle the user input on the final test

3) You probably want to change the `< 10` to be `<= 10`

Answer (score 0):

Make the `print("Entered interest rate is greater than 10%. Are you sure? (y/n): ")` an input

```
answer = int(input("Are you sure?"))
if answer == "y":
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    if 0 <= interest_rate < 10:
        break
    elif interest_rate > 10:
        print("Entered interest rate is greater than 10%. Are you sure? (y/n): ")
```

can be:

```
if 0 <= interest_rate <= 10:
    break
print("Entered interest rate is greater than 10%. Are you sure? (y/n): ")
```

except the last line must take the response and process it.

Your `else` was not related to an `if`

Your `elif` was unnecessary after `break`

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to break down the solution and validation into different modules. Please check the below code to see how I break them down. So it is easy when it comes to debugging and testing.

```
def validating_user_input(num):
    """
    """
    return num > 0

def getting_user_input():
    """
    """
    user_input = int(raw_input("Enter the number that is greater than 0: "))
    return user_input

def confirming_choose():
    """
    """
    try:
        user_choose = int(raw_input("Can you confirm your input? [0|1]? "))
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return user_choose == 1



def main():
    """
    """
    initial_cond = True
    while initial_cond:
        user_input = getting_user_input()
        if validating_user_input(user_input):
            if user_input > 10:
                confirmation = confirming_choose()
                while not confirmation:
                    getting_user_input()
                #do you operating here
            initial_cond = False
        else:
            print "It is not valid input."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```